# Saving outputs of loop into a column in dataframe

Tags: python

Hi I'm having this problem where I'm getting a range a values from a loop in python and I want to save them in a column in an existing dataframe? But as can be seen from the image, It is not saving each value as its being calculated, It's instead just saving the last value. I printed the values underneath the table for clarity. Also the first table can be ignore also. It's just the table with CO2 and AER I'm worried about.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TfSa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `df['Aer'] = Aer` sets the value in every row of the table.  You probably want to set that column to 0 to begin with:

```
df['Aer'] = 0
```

then in your loop do:

```
    df.at{i,'Aer'] = Aer
```

As I side note, you should have posted your source as text instead of as an image.  It's not cool to make us bring up an image to view.

Comment: Sorry about that I'm new to this site. When I put that in I get an error. However if i write it like, df.at ['Aer' , i] = Aer it prints a new row labelled Aer and my correct values, While an existing column labelled Aer has all values equal to zero. How do I get my correct values printed into the column?

Comment: What error do you get?  What I wrote should work.

Comment: It is a very long error with the following at the end. 'TypeError: cannot insert DatetimeIndex with incompatible label'.

Comment: Ah.  OK, then `df.at[df.iloc[i].name,'Aer'] = Aer` should be better.  You have to look up the value of the index for row #i.

Comment: Can you expand further on the value of the index for row #i?

Comment: Hi, I got it working. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!